# Text to Speech Xamarin Essentials, play and pause audio button

Tags: xamarin.forms

Hi I am trying to allow users to play and pause the audio of the text extracted from ocr process. I wanted to use one button for them to be able to play and pause the audio. I am using xamarin forms and xamarin essentials text to speech api. How am I able to apply a button for this to happen?

Comment: TTS does not have any functions to allow pausing the playback